# Angular/RXJS, How do I sort an Observable Array of objects based on a SPECIFIC String value?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I have an interesting problem (I think) and would love some help.

I am returning an Observable[DisplayCard[]] that is filtered based on a value. That all works great. After I filter that array based on a value, I NOW want to sort the returned array by another one of it's values called `category`. `category` can only be one of three String values: `ONGOING`, `UPCOMING`, and `PAST`.

**I want to return an array that will sort like this:** ONGOING --> UPCOMING --> PAST. So, all the display cards that have "ONGOING" will be in front, after there is no more of those, I want all the "UPCOMING" cards and then after those, I want all the "PAST" cards to show.

Here is my code:

```
displayCommunityCards$ = this.cardService.displayCards$
    .pipe(
      map(communityEventsCards => communityEventsCards.filter(community => community.type === 'COMMUNITY EVENT')
        .sort((a, b) => {
          return ???
        }),
      tap(data => console.log('Community Cards: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating an enum to represent all possible values for `CardCategory` and defining the order they should be sorted in using `Record<CardCategory, number>`:

```js
export enum CardCategory {
  OnGoing  = 'ONGOING',
  Upcoming = 'UPCOMING',
  Past     = 'PAST',
}

export const CategorySortOrder: Record<CardCategory, number> = {
  'ONGOING'  : 0,
  'UPCOMING' : 1,
  'PAST'     : 2
}
```

Then create a sort function that uses that to sort:

```js
function sortByCardCategory(a: DisplayCard, b: DisplayCard) {  
  if(a.category === b.category) return 0;
  return CategorySortOrder[a.category] > CategorySortOrder[b.category] ? 1 : -1;
}
```

You can now easily sort like this:

```js
displayCommunityCards$ = this.cardService.displayCards$.pipe(
  map(cards => cards
    .filter(c => c.type === CardType.CommunityEvent)
    .sort(sortByCardCategory)
  )
);
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-69690223-b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard.service.ts) demo.

---

Using the [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) type isn't completely necessary, but it does guarantee that you define a sort order for all values of `CardCategory`.  For example, if you added a new `CardCategory`, typescript will throw an error about `CategorySortOrder` not defining all values of `CardCategory`.

[image: screenshot of error]

```
Property 'MYNEWCAT' is missing in type
'{ 
  UPCOMING: number; 
  ONGOING: number; 
  PAST: number; 
}' 
but required in type 'Record<CardCategory, number>'. (2741)
```

Comment: Hey! I actually really like this way the most so far! is your ```export function sortByCardCategory(a: DisplayCard, b: DisplayCard)``` a new TS file?

Comment: If you want it to be :-)

Sometimes I just put utility functions like this in the same .ts file as the component that is using it (as I did in the StackBlitz).  Of course if it will be used elsewhere, it makes sense to move it up the folder hierarchy  to a common place. The reason I don't put it in the component itself is because it's just a pure function that returns a boolean value and does not use any state from the component.

Comment: I gotcha. I just tried your second option using the generic one. It doesn't quite work for me. It sorts the ONGOING perfectly by placing it first, but then it doesn't have the UPCOMING Card go behind it.. So close I can taste it haha

Comment: Just tried it. Seems to work great. I had to switch your order in your CategorySortOrder so ONGOING is 0 instead of UPCOMING. But Just tried it in all my cards and it sorts correctly. Appreciate it!!

Comment: This works too. An enum is already in order though, they are 'enumerated' (0,1,2,...). Also if you don't sort inside of the observable pipe, you can pass the observable through different sorting functions if you ever want to add the option to change the order or add filters. If they are already sorted in the observable you would be sorting twice or sorting items that are then fitlered. You could also make extra observables each with different sorting piping the unsorted observable if you like it better that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this by creating three array and merge them in order. It can be done in O(n).

```js
const upcoming = [],
      past = [],
      ongoing = [];
      
const events = [{event: "upcoming", id: 1}, {event: "upcoming", id: 2}, {event: "past", id: 3}, {event: "past", id: 4}, {event: "ongoing", id: 5}];

events.forEach(el => {
   el.event === "upcoming" ? upcoming.push(el) : 
   el.event === "past" ? past.push(el) :
   el.event === "ongoing" ? ongoing.push(el) : false;
});

console.log([...ongoing, ...upcoming, ...past]);
```

In the above snippet the memory used will be more.

> I want to return an array that will sort like this: ONGOING -->
> UPCOMING --> PAST. So, all the display cards that have "ONGOING" will
> be in front, after there is no more of those, I want all the
> "UPCOMING" cards and then after those, I want all the "PAST" cards to
> show.

Another interesting way could be creating keys in an object with "ongoing", "upcoming" and "past". You can create an array as value for each and push things once you find it. You need to check when to start show the upcoming events and when to start past.

```js
 const result = {
          upcoming: [],
          past: [],
          ongoing: [] 
 }
          
    const events = [{event: "upcoming", id: 1}, {event: "upcoming", id: 2}, {event: "past", id: 3}, {event: "past", id: 4}, {event: "ongoing", id: 5}];

    events.forEach(el => {
       el.event === "upcoming" ? result.upcoming.push(el) : 
       el.event === "past" ? result.past.push(el) :
       el.event === "ongoing" ? result.ongoing.push(el) : false;
    });

 console.log(result);
```

When you are done, just take the key and throw the data to the view.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to thank you for taking the time in helping me with this problem. I don't think this is the way I want to go as the answer given by the person above seems to fit the style and design of my app. Again, I don't want you to think you did it for nothing as it is still a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answer works, you don't need to create multiple arrays or even subscribe to achieve this. You are always better of just using **async pipes** in your template and providing the **sorting function** to use on the result of the async pipes.

The **Enum** & **Interface** used in this example:

```js
enum Cat {
  ONGOING = 'ONGOING',
  UPCOMING = 'UPCOMING',
  PAST = 'PAST',
}

interface DisplayCommunityCards {
  category: Cat;
  type: string;
}
```

In your component:

```js
cards$ = of([
  { category: Cat.ONGOING, type: 'COMMUNITY EVENT' },
  { category: Cat.PAST, type: 'COMMUNITY EVENT' },
  { category: Cat.PAST, type: 'COMMUNITY EVENT' },
  { category: Cat.UPCOMING, type: 'COMMUNITY EVENT' },
]);

displayCommunityCards$ = this.cards$.pipe(
  map((communityEventsCards) =>
    communityEventsCards.filter(
      (community) => community.type === 'COMMUNITY EVENT'
    )
  )
);

sort(
  displayCommunityCards: DisplayCommunityCards[]
): DisplayCommunityCards[] {
  const catOrder = Object.values(Cat);
  return displayCommunityCards.sort((a, b) => {
    return catOrder.indexOf(a.category) - catOrder.indexOf(b.category);
  });
}
```

*(cards$ is just a replacement for the observable that you are getting from your service.)*

In your template:

```html
<p *ngFor="let c of sort(displayCommunityCards$ | async)" >
  {{ c.category }}
</p>
```

*By doing it this way you will not have to worry about unsubscibing in an onDestroy and you are able to use the OnPush ChangeDetectionStrategy.*

Here is an example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vqhy9h?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: This is the solution I want to follow, but I do my template a little bit different like so: ``` <ion-row *ngIf="displayOurCommunityCards$ | async as ourCommunityCards">``` and then I do an ngFor on my cards: ```<ion-card *ngFor="let card of ourCommunityCards; let i = index"```. where should I put the syntax you provided in my template?

Comment: I would think: ***ngFor="let card of sort(ourCommunityCards); let i = index"**. If you make a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) I would gladly help you out with your code.

Comment: I already accepted the other answer, but I did actually try that and I was getting some very strange errors/pages not loading so I just went a different route... I really do appreciate you taking into consideration of my design and building off of it!